# strcpy: Use a char** variable in union as an argument

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, strcpy

Hello I am trying to copy a string into "word" variable.
strcpy requires char* type, and my "word" variable is char** type.
How do I make it happen?
I tried following, but it does not work.

```
struct command
{
  enum command_type type;
  char *input;
  char *output;
  union
  {
    struct command *command[2];
    char **word;
  } u;
};


main(){
...
char* charPtr = "abc";
struct command* cmdPtr;
strcpy(cmdPtr->u.word,charPtr);
...
}
```

Comment: You start by allocating some memory, as the undefined behavior in this is rampant.

Comment: To start with, a pointer to a pointer to `char` is not a string. If anything it *might* be an array of strings. Secondly, in your code snippet you do not actually initialize the structure pointer, so it points to some undefined location. And when you make `cmdPtr` point somewhere valid, then you need to initialize the pointers *in* the structure, including the ones in the array.

Comment: Do you just want to make the program compile, or do you want to to be able to run as well?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan LOLz, thats an *awesome* question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct command
{
    ...
    union
    {
        ...
        char **word;          // <-- requires memory to be associated explicitly 
    } u;
};
...
char* charPtr = "abc";
struct command* cmdPtr;           // <-- uninitialized variable
strcpy(cmdPtr->u.word,charPtr);   // <-- undefined behavior
```

`cmdPtr` is uninitialized, which means that dereferencing of this pointer invokes an ***undefined behavior*** already. Even if you would allocate a memory for this `struct`, you also have to allocate the memory for the `word` member, otherwise `strcpy` tries to copy string to the invalid memory, yielding an undefined behavior again.

Additionally the return value of your `main` is not defined and the `word` is declared as `char**` while `strcpy` expects the first argument of type `char*`. For example you could do:

```
struct command cmd;
char myBuffer[255];
char* pBuffer = &myBuffer[0];
cmd.u.word = &pBuffer;
strcpy(*cmd.u.word, "abc");
printf("%s", *cmd.u.word);
```

or instead of making `word` to point to local pointer:

```
cmd.u.word = malloc(sizeof(char*));
*cmd.u.word = &myBuffer[0];
```

... but once you start allocating stuff dynamically, be careful to properly free / deallocate it as well.

Comment: Thank you LihO. Is it possible to use malloc instead of myBuffer[255]?